# Как отправить в сообщении ранее загруженный файл в Telethon

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, изображения, telethon

С помощью

```
file = await client.upload_file('photo.jpg')
```

Telethon загружает файл на сервер. Тем самым мы можем получить ID файла.

Я хочу избежать многократной загрузки, загрузив один раз файл на сервер для того, чтобы потом отправлять его в сообщениях по ID.

Как это сделать?

**UPD:**

Алгоритм:

```
ID = загрузить из файла конфигурации

Если на сервере нет файла ID:
    ID = Загрузить файл на сервер
    Записать ID в конфигурационный файл
иначе:
    Отправить в чат по ID (как, если знаем только числа?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для загрузки файла на сервер с помощью Telethon и получения его ID, вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

api_id = 'YOUR_API_ID'
api_hash = 'YOUR_API_HASH'
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

async def upload_file(file_path):
    try:
        result = await client.upload_file(file_path)
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error uploading file: {e}")
        return None

async def main():
    file_path = 'photo.jpg'
    uploaded_file = await upload_file(file_path)
    if uploaded_file:
        file_id = uploaded_file.id
        print(f"File ID: {file_id}")

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

В этом коде мы создаем функцию `upload_file`, которая принимает путь к файлу и загружает его на сервер с помощью одноимённого метода. Затем в основной функции мы вызываем эту функцию для загрузки файла и выводим его ID.

Вы можете сохранить полученный ID файла и использовать его для отправки файла в сообщениях или других операциях, чтобы избежать повторной загрузки файла на сервер.

Comment: Спасибо!

Но при перезапуске бота придётся файл загружать заново. Что, если сделать следующим образом (см. обновил вопрос, раздел UPD), иначе здесь форматирования нет и нечитабельно.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ

Отправляем на сервер:

```
file = await client.upload_file('image.jpg')
```

Можно посмотреть данные файла, если совсем хочется:

```
print(file)
```

Результат будет примерно таким:

```
InputFile(id=00000, parts=1, name='image.jpg', md5_checksum='00000')
```

Все эти данные сохраняем в конфигурацию и при последующей загрузке создаём:

```
from telethon.tl.types import InputFile
... 
file = InputFile(id=load_id, parts=load_parts, name=load_name, md5_checksum=load_md5)
```

Отправляем ответом с сообщением, либо с помощью других методов Telethon:

```
await event.respond(message=text, file=file)
```

Если при отправке возникает ошибка, то загружаем файл заново и получаем новые характеристики (ID, parts, name, md5), которые записываем в config.

Поправьте, если я где-то ошибаюсь